# Shared memory in chroot environment

Tags: ubuntu, android, postgresql, chroot

I'm playing with Ubuntu 11.10 launched in a chroot environment under Android 3.2.1. Most of the software works fine except PostgreSQL. When installed or initdb launched it's saying:

> FATAL: could not create shared memory segment: Function not implemented.
>   DETAIL: Failed Failed system call was shmget(key=1, size=1908736, 03600).

Is there any specific tuning of shared memory/PostgreSQL in a chroot? Perhaps some kind of mount the android ashmem to chrooted shm? I'm a novice in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

*ashmem* uses the `/dev/ashmem` device node. You need to create it in the chroot's `/dev`, either by using `mknod` with the apropriate numbers, or by doing a bind mount:

```
touch chroot/dev/ashmem
mount --bind /dev/ashmem chroot/dev/ashmem
```

(You might need Busybox or Ubuntu's `mount` for this.)

Comment: Thanks. Mount failed with error "Not a directory". Have tried ln /dev/ashmem $chroot/dev/ashmem - failed cross-device link. Tried mknod, but still same error. Have also experimented with creating $chroot/dev/shm device with no success.

Comment: @Stan: 1) apparently the Linux version used by Android does not yet support file bindmounts; 2) obvious; 3) impossible, as mknod does not create links -- but a *different* error message might occur; 4) `ashmem`, not `shm`.

Comment: The commands above wont work because touch creates a file rather than a directory. You need to do the bind mount from Android shell before you chroot into your Ubuntu chroot. `mkdir chroot/dev; mount -o bind /dev /chroot/dev` works fine for me in lollipop. However, having /dev/ashmem accessible in your Ubuntu chroot isn't going to help. PostgresSQL is looking for Posix shared memory (/dev/shm).