# Shared memory in chroot environment for postgresql: permission denied?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Attempting to set up chroot environment in which to run postgresql 9.5 (this is to allow a shadow data partition while using the same configuration). I get the following error:

```
 FATAL:  could not open shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1804289383": Permission denied
```

This was similar to [Shared memory in chroot environment](https://superuser.com/questions/350287/shared-memory-in-chroot-environment). But `dev` was already bound, so it was obviously not the right answer.

More info: RHEL7 systemd, linux 3.10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/dev/shm` was the missing component.

```
mount -t tmpfs tmp /dev/shm
```

solved the problem